# epsilon delta proof for $\frac{1}{1+x^2} -1$

Tags: calculus

> Show that given $\epsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that $\left|\frac{1}{1+x^2}-{1}\right|<0$ whenever $|x|<\delta$.

Comment: I really want to help here, so let me know if there are any questions.  I just want to give you the best answer I can.

Comment: can't understand the first equality sorry

Comment: That's an easy one to answer ... just get a common denominator.  Then $1-(1+x^2)=-x^2$.  Taking the absolute and there you have it.

Comment: @OliverBrooks: You selected an answer that you didn't quite seem to understand it. It is for folks who knew just a little bit of math than you did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First write

$$\left|\frac{1}{1+x^2}-1\right|=\left|\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}\right|$$

Note that $1+x^2>1$ implies that $\frac{1}{1+x^2}<1$.  Using this inequality reveals

$$\left|\frac{1}{1+x^2}-1\right|=\left|\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}\right|<x^2$$

So, for all $\epsilon>0$,

$$\left|\frac{1}{1+x^2}-1\right|=x^2<\epsilon$$

whenever $|x|<\sqrt{\epsilon}$.

Choose $\delta<\sqrt{\epsilon}$ and you have it!  If you don't like the square root of epsilon, then first choose $\delta <\frac12$.  Then,

$$\left|\frac{1}{1+x^2}-1\right|=x^2<\frac12 |x|<\epsilon$$

whenever $\delta =\min\left(\frac12,2\epsilon\right)$.

Comment: >can't wrap my brain on how you do the first step - sorry    $$\left|\frac{1}{1+x^2}-1\right|=\left|\frac{x^2}{1+x^2}\right|$$

Comment: Oh ... just get a common denominator.  And that's all.

Comment: fabulous....i see it clearly now.

Comment: Fantastic!!  I love it when a plan comes together.

Answer (score 2):

**hint**: $\left|\dfrac{1}{1+x^2}-1\right| = \dfrac{|x|^2}{1+x^2} < |x|^2$